# React Console Error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in ...\node_modules\react-popper\lib

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

Upon running `npm start` by React DOM and Console return the following:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ../node_modules/react-popper/lib/Manager.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in >'C:\Users\B\Desktop\Programming\WebDev\ProjectFile\node_modules\react-popper\lib'

I have already attempted to run `npm install react-popper`, `npm install react`, and deleted the `...\node_modules\react-popper` file and reinstalled react-popper.

Consistently the same error has applied. Is this something that is possible to solve through node?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-popper/issues/82